# Mixta vs Mezcla - Best usage for "tabla mixta"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, sintaxis

Why do people call it a **tabla mixta**? Why not a **tabla mezcla**?

Tabla mixta is a food with two or more items, but it sounds wrong.

Mixta? Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DRAE

> **[mixto, ta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PRHgusG)**
>
> 1. **adj**. Formado por varios elementos que se **mezclan** para componer otro. Apl. a cosa, u. t. c. s. m.

Check the entry for [Mezcla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P9Hobgp) as well.

Take into account that all the meanings of *mezcla* are nouns, but the one that matters for this case for *mixta* is an adjective.

When you are saying that that dish is a *tabla mixta* you express that is a "tabla" (a small board of wood to hold your food) and "mixta" is and adjective used to express that contains an assortment of things.

You could call it "tabla mezclada" but not "mezcla" because, as a noun, can't auqlify "tabla" the same way.

Answer (score 3):

*Others have clarified that an adjective made from the verb* mezclar *is actually* mezclado -- *in this case, the feminine*, mezclada.

I will focus on when a Spanish learner should choose *mixto* versus *mezclado*, to express what in English is expressed with "mixed."

All dictionaries seem to give examples of *mixto* for mixed gender groups (see e.g. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/mixed)).  Some dictionaries include a food example as well (see e.g. [spanishdict.com](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/mixed) *mixed salad* ensalada mixta).

If you look in a usage collection resource such as linguee.com, you'll see many more examples of *mixto*, in contexts as varied as photographic techniques, economics, engineering, etc.

Here is a guide for choosing between *mezclado* and *mixto*:

1. *Mezclado* suggests a true blending into something homogeneous (for example *La mezcla de ketchup y mayonesa se la conoce como "thousand island dressing"* | The mixture of ketchup and mayonnaise is known as Thousand Island dressing), whereas *mixto* is more of a potpourri or combo.  For example, restaurant menus in the US will offer a "combo platter" which has a combination of two or three different menu items.  This is similar to your example, *tabla mixta*.
2. Novel combinations of techniques or approaches get described with *mixto* because they are a hybrid.  If it helps, you might think of the Yiddish *mishmash* (where the last syllable is pronounced like the English word "mush," not like the English word "mash").
3. There is a special case, mixed race, which traditionally is expressed as either *mestizo* or *mixto*.  This is a bit old-fashioned, in both languages.  Nowadays, where you see *mixed race* or *hapa* in English, you might see *mezcolanza* in Spanish.  Example:

   > "¿De dónde eres?"
   >
   > "Soy una mezcolanza.  Mi mamá es dominicana y mi papá es italiano; yo me crié principalmente en Nueva York."

Answer (score 1):

"Mezcla" is a noun and not an adjective.

The correct adjective for something that is mixed is "mixto".